# Why do I get different output in c++?

Tags: c++, compilation

```
int main(){

    int x;
    cout<<"enter a number: ";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<endl;
    odd(x);


    return 0;
}

void odd(int a){

if(a%2 != 0){

    cout<<"the number is odd : "<< '(' +a+ ')';

    }else{

    even(a);

    }
}
```

I executed the above program and i get different output:

```
enter a number: 15

the number is odd : 96
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: C++ doesn't have string concatenation, and it *definitely* doesn't have number-to-string conversion like other languages. @MikolajMularczyk's answer is correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this: `cout<<"the number is odd : "<< '('<< a << ')';`

"(" and ")" in ASCII have values 40 and 41. They are promoted to int and you add them, that is why your output is 96 (40 + 15 + 41 == 96).